# How to compute a value for a column in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I would like to compute a value (number) which should be presented in a column (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator).

I know the way of "mutation" which has the downside of manipulating the objects.

Another approach would be "formatting" which has downside that the result is of type string and other feature like sorting and sum etc. are not available.

So the question is: is there a way to compute a value ?

Comment: You answered your own question there, the correct answer is mutators

Comment: Seems to me a mutator is exactly what you are looking for. I don't understand your comment "has the downside of manipulating the objects." What does it matter what Tabulator's internal object contains. It's not like it's going to modify your original data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cellEdited callback and add a function that calculates the values.

sample function:

```
    var mcalcHour=function(cell){
        var rdata=cell._cell.row.data;
        rdata.rc_total = (rdata.hourly_rate * rdata.hours);     
    }
```